# Xcode - thread_policy_set(1) returned 46

Tags: xcode

Is there any option/argument in Xcode to hide this annoying console output?

The console is constantly spitting out:

```
thread_policy_set(1) returned 46
thread_policy_set(1) returned 46
thread_policy_set(1) returned 46
thread_policy_set(1) returned 46
thread_policy_set(1) returned 46
thread_policy_set(1) returned 46
thread_policy_set(1) returned 46
thread_policy_set(1) returned 46
thread_policy_set(1) returned 46
thread_policy_set(1) returned 46
thread_policy_set(1) returned 46
thread_policy_set(1) returned 46
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did u get a solution to this?

Comment: Nope, I'm assuming it's some build setting related to core data warning suppression though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We noticed this happening with a library `react-native-ux-cam` in our RN application. Not sure if you are using RN but maybe take a look at your dependencies and try removing some of them to see if that helps narrow down where the problem exists.

Anyone looking at this for RN specifically, I started removing packages that I knew would be updating a lot, like monitoring dependencies such as `react-native-ux-cam`. I opened up an issue [here](https://github.com/negativetwelve/react-native-ux-cam/issues/139)

Comment: Also used UXCam for this project, so that must be it! Nice spot finding that!